How to use BusOutbox in consumer scope?
Bus is configured like this (using RabbitMq):
busConfigurator.AddEntityFrameworkOutbox<MyDbContext>(o =>
{
    o.UsePostgres();
    o.UseBusOutbox();
});

and it works fine in controller:
class MyController
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;

    private readonly IPublishEndpoint _publishEndpoint;

    public MyController(MyDbContext dbContext, IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _publishEndpoint = publishEndpoint;
    }

    public async Task Handle()
    {
        await _dbContext.Add(...);
        await _publishEndpoint.Publish(new OtherMessage()); // <-- is being send through outbox after _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync() below
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

However it does not work in consumer or any service which is consumer dependency:
class MyConsumer : IConsumer<MyMessage>
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;

    private readonly IPublishEndpoint _publishEndpoint;

    public MyConsumer(MyDbContext dbContext, IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _publishEndpoint = publishEndpoint;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MyMessage> context)
    {
        await _publishEndpoint.Publish(new OtherMessage()); // is being sent directly to message broker before exception is thrown
        throw new Exception("test");
    }
}

As far as I know (from docs) it's expected behaviour because consumer outbox is not configured. If I add following configuration:
busConfigurator.AddConfigureEndpointsCallback((context, name, cfg) =>
{
    cfg.UseEntityFrameworkOutbox<MyDbContext>(context);
});

Then it works inside consumer, message is not published after exception is thrown, because as far as I know now it uses transactional outbox and also "Consume" method is "wrapped" with transaction.
However now (with consumer outbox) I also don't have control on transaction:
class MyConsumer : IConsumer<MyMessage>
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;

    private readonly IPublishEndpoint _publishEndpoint;

    public MyConsumer(MyDbContext dbContext, IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _publishEndpoint = publishEndpoint;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MyMessage> context)
    {
        await _publishEndpoint.Publish(new OtherMessage()); // is being sent through outbox even if I don't call _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()
    }
}

Which is very annoying. Is there a way to achieve BusOutbox behaviour inside consumer? I only want to atomically send message when I explicitly call _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync() and I don't want transaction to be created "wrapping" Consume method.
Using MassTransit 8.2.0.

Short answer, no, you have to use the consumer outbox as outlined in the documentation. You can't use the "bus" outbox in a consumer, MassTransit controls the transaction intentionally to ensure exactly once delivery.

I was wondering why it is designed this way - what if "at least once" delivery is sufficient (if for example message fails to be ACKed after message published from consumer is persisted to outbox then message is consumed again and same other message published through outbox again) - it's because exactly-once is "better" and this is way works like this? But in theory it would be possible to implement BusOutbox behaviour like in my question above?

Also, does it mean that current behaviour opens connection to db (starts transaction) before consuming message and commits it after message is consumed? So if for example my consumer performs some tasks not related to db for 10 seconds, and then publishes message, does it mean that such consumer will "block" one db connection (from connection pool) for 10 seconds?

Yes, it does block a connection in the transaction.
